# Building a simple wedding RSVP system with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I am contemplating building a website for my wedding next year. It would contain information about the event, photos and blogs from my fiancee and I.... you get the picture.

One feature i'd like if possible would be a way of letting my guests RSVP online. I envision that their physical invite has a passcode, which they enter into a text field on the site and tick whether they can or can't attend.

The passcode they entered will be compared against a secure guest-list containing names and passcodes. If it doesn't match, they receive an error message, if there is match however, the information is then relayed to me via email. I will probably build the site using Wordpress, so I would be dealing with PHP.

Can anyone recommend how i might approach this project, as being a front-end dev I have absolutely no idea and my ambition exceeds my limited PHP knowledge.

Would love to hear your ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Cheers for the edit Dave. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in generalities, for this sort of thing I find it useful to start by outlining the various components of the system.

While the info pages can be static, you'll need a database to which you can persist your invite data, so I'd start by thinking about the data entities. Devise a list of entities that will exist in the system that might need data tables. E.g. invite, blog post etc.

Then think about the operations that need to be performed on those entities. Are they read-only? Do you need to create new ones, or modify existing ones? You'll need to write code to perform those operations at some point.

Then think about the various ways information from those entities might need to be presented to the user. This gives you an idea of what templates you'll need to build.

If you're thinking of using Wordpress, you can cover off the blog functionality and static page stuff using that application alone. You'd then need to think about how the RSVP functionality might be implemented separately to Wordpress, or within it as a plugin. If you're really lucky, there might be a plugin out there already that will do what you need - or something similar that you can augment yourself.

If you're new to the backend side of things I'd recommend building a blog + static page site using Wordpress, getting it "done" and then looking at the RSVP stuff as a second phase. At least then if it proves unfeasible you still have a useful working site.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Yes, its my intention to build a wordpress/ partially static site and then build this RSPV system into that. I suspected there would need to be some comms with the database for the guest list, but was wondering whether I could get around this using a pure php solution. It really doesn't have to be too tidy underneath, its only for my eyes.

But yes, great idea to plan it out. I will ask myself those questions.

Comment: Glad to hear it, you're welcome. If this answer was satisfactory, would you mind "ticking" it as the solution to your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd build this as a simple plugin for WordPress and create an additional DB table that would hold the name against the passcode (this could be auto-generated based on the ID or otherwise).

You could then make a simple admin page when you can add new guests and check the response of guests.

Answer (score 0):

First: congratulations with your marriage. From what I understand you have very little knowledge of PHP so start with reading a few books or articles about basic PHP/MySql. Then, put your ideas in a drawing or flowchart and just go for it. Make lots of mistakes, learn from them, ask for help on SO or a PHP colleague or friend. And above all, have fun doing it.

Comment: Ok cool, seems like using the Wordpress DB looks like the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes I would install the contact 7 plugin. In the contact form, add passcode as a required text input. Have the results emailed to you and to them. They could make up the passcode which is the downside.

This doesn't have all the options you are wanting but you can either spend several hours writing your own php code and then trouble shoot it, or just install the plugin and be done in 30 minutes.